# checking dynamically created textboxes for values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, dynamic

I am creating a form for inserting data which technologies are being used by which customers.

I get data of customer's ID and name and select a customer in an drop-down list, and i get data from technologies id and description and display description in a table + it creates a textbox `(ID='box-". $row1['ID_T']."')` for every technology entry in a DB.

So now i would like to check this dynamically created textboxes with jquery for value (if empty or filled with data) (`getelementbyid`) but i can not find a way to check theese DYN textboxes.

The `ID_T` and `ID_C` will be loaded into another table containing these two PK's  and add string from textbox to value. 
i would appreciate your help so much!

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <SCRIPT>
            function update_tech(id,description) 
            {
                var x = confirm('Do you want to edit technology '+description);
                if (x == true)
            {
            document.getElementById('update_id').value = id;
            //document.getElementById('description').value = description;
            //document.form_update.submit();
            }
            }    
        </SCRIPT>
    </HEAD>
    <?php
        include "connection.php";
        $sql = "SELECT ID_C, Name FROM empresa";
        $rs = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
        $sql2 = "SELECT ID_T, description FROM technologies";
        $rs2 = mysql_query($sql2, $conn);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs2)) 
        {
        if (isset($_POST["box-".$row["ID_T"]]))
            if ($_POST["box-".$row["ID_T"]] != "")
                echo "INSERT ....".$_POST["box-".$row["ID_T"]]."<br>";  
        }
        $rs2 = mysql_query($sql2, $conn);
        mysql_close($conn);
    ?> 
    <BODY>
        <SELECT NAME="customers" ONCHANGE="showCustomer(this.value)">
        <?php
            if (mysql_num_rows($rs))
            {
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
            {
        ?>          
<option value='<?php echo $row['ID_C'] ?>'><?php echo $row['Name']?></option>    
        <?php
                }
            }
            else {
            echo "<option value=\"0\">No customers</option>"; 
            }
        ?>
        </SELECT>
        <FORM METHOD="POST">
        <?php
            echo "<table border='0'>";
            while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($rs2)) 
            {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td><INPUT TYPE='text' name='box-". $row1['ID_T']."' ID='box-". $row1['ID_T']."'></td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row1['description'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            } 
            echo "</TABLE>";
        ?>
        <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT">
    </FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either maintain an array of input box ids or use the jquery partial selector to identify all the input boxes.

jQuery approach is something like:

```
$('input[id^="box-"]').each(function(e, i) { console.log(e); };
```